# Install Grafana on OSX Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, grafana

Has anyone been able to install Grafana on a Mac?

Please share how you did it and what software/tools I will need to install.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question leaves a lot to be desired... Have you already tried http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/ but are running into problems? If so, what problems/errors are you seeing? While the referenced link is pretty helpful, I too, am running into issues getting the CSS for the UI to work. Is this what you're seeing too?

Answer (score 2):

There is no pre build install package for OSX yet.

But you can build it pretty easily if you have Go and Nodejs installed:
http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/

Comment: No package for OS X yet... Does that mean you're working on one Torkel?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed that using brew install grafana/grafana/grafana http://docs.grafana.org/installation/mac/